# How to get Base URL with port number in codeigniter 3.0.3

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am currently using codeigniter 3.0.3 .I tried to get base url using `var_dump(base_url());`function 
 i got this result

> string 'http://localhost/' (length=17)

But I need to get base URL with port number.I got it in codeigniter 3.0.2 like this

> string 'http://localhost:8000'

How to get Base URL with port number in codeigniter 3.0.3.

Comment: Set `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8000/';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `base_url` in `config.php` like this

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';`

Comment: but when I open it as usual localhost/projectname didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You could trim the trailing slash from the base url, and add the port number of the current request, like this:

```
$trimmedBaseUrl = rtrim(base_url(), '/');
$serverPort = $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];
$newBaseUrl = "$trimmedBaseUrl:$serverPort/";

var_dump($newBaseUrl);
```

Comment: I think, it  
 `$trimmedBaseUrl = rtrim('/', base_url());`  
should be
  `$trimmedBaseUrl = rtrim(base_url(), '/');` 
See: [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this

```
var_dump(base_url().$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']);
```